# Android Geocoding Results click listener

Tags: android, geocoding, arcgis

I am developing an ArcGIS app for android, I used the sample code found in [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/concepts/index.html#//011900000046000000) and its working perfectly. Now my question is how to set an onClickListener || OnSingleTapListener  on the geocoding results displayed in the graphic layer.

Comment: what had you tried and where did you failed?

Comment: I have extracted the X and Y from the graphicLayer graphics yet I can't depend on that because the user must click the same exact coordinates which is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

(Can't access the code you're linking, I get 404'd).

I guess the results are created dynamically. So you need their View (or any subclasses) references in order to use

```
myResult.setOnClickListener(myClickListener)
```

Then the listener will handle the click Event.

Comment: my bad fixed the link can you please check it again ? thanks !